# Create ids of an igraph graph using "internal" ids

Tags: r, igraph, social-networking

I'm using igraph package in R. I've created a random smallworld graph using 
sample_smallworld function. Now I'd like to set ids of the vertices of this new graph equal to their "internal" ids (i.e. to those "ids" which one gets using print(V(graphname)) ). How can I do it?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I find your question a bit unclear. Maybe `V(g)$name <- as_ids(V(g))`?

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn implicit names into explicit names like this:

```
V(g)$name <- as_ids(V(g))
```